# How to get DateTime in the format (DD/MM or MM/DD) but taking culture into account

Tags: c#, wpf, date

So I have a problem where I want to display the date as 07/04 like 7 April but this needs to take culture into account. So if the user is using en-US it needs to display as 04/07.

I've tired using MonthDayPattern but that gives the month written out as in April instead of 07.

I have an idea that works and that's using the ToShortDate which gives dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy and then removing the yyyy part which gives it in the correct culture format but that feels a bit hacky and I'm sure somewhere there is a formatter that could do this.

Update for clarity:

I want the month and day to display in numbers as in 07 (for day) and 04 (for month) but in the order that is given by the culture.

Comment: Your requirement is just as "hacky" as the proposed solution. The order is part of the culture so you cannot display a date as dd/MM and also take the culture info an account. This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I think your hack makes sense, you can create DTO/ViewModel/ValueObject to hold all information

Comment: Sorry I might have explained incorrectly. I want the month and day to display in numbers as in 07 (for day) and 04 (for month) but in the order that is given by the culture. Like I said the ToMonthDay method that is built in on the culture gives me the correct order but I want the month to display as MM.

Comment: DateTime is meant to be formatted for presentation. Your format is not included in the standard formats, but nobody stops you from generating your own [IFormatProvider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider) that can be used by almost all CultureInfo providers. You could use [DateTimeFormatInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo) class with a custom `IFormatProvider` and [ICustomFormatter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icustomformatter).  Don't forget about the `DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator`

Comment: These classes and methods are there to provide standard implementations to this kind of requirements.

Comment: @Jimi That doesn't really solve the basic problem, which is that a cultureinfo object can't provide the preferred order of the month and day of month components of a date. So you end up having to handle each culture manually

Comment: @Jonas Høgh  The `ShortDatePattern` always provides that order. Then you decide how to handle it. E.g., `var ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ja-JA");` (will give you `yyyy/MM/dd`), then, maybe: `var dtf = ci.DateTimeFormat; string sep = dtf.DateSeparator; string order = string.Join(sep, dtf.ShortDatePattern.Trim($"{sep}yyyy".ToCharArray()).Split(char.Parse(sep)).Select(s => s.Length == 1 ? s+s: s));` will return `MM/dd`. `th-TH -> d/M/yyyy -> dd/MM, en-US -> M/d/yyyy -> MM/dd`. With just trivial string manipulation. You can elaborate on that. `ShortDatePattern` is consistent.

Comment: Sure, you can do the year removal hack suggested by the OP on the format level instead of manipulating the output date, but now you're making assumptions about where the year part is relative to the separator. Do they hold for all cultures?

Comment: @Jonas Høgh (You didn't @Me). Since when parsing strings is a *hack*? Provided that it was just an example, `DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern` is a standard format. See what you get from this: `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Select(c => c.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern).ToList().ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f));`. Related to: [Date format by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country), from the adoption of ISO 8601. You can generate a (much) more consistent procedure, implementing a specific IFormatProvider (which exists for this reason).

Comment: @Jimi manipulating strings is fine, but that is a naïve solution to a complex i18n problem. There are a lot of date formats in the world. E.g. in the Bulgarian CultureInfo ("bg-BG") the ShortDatePattern is `d.M.yyyy 'г.'` Should the literal "r." at the end be included in dates with no year?

Comment: @Jonas Høgh This could be an interesting discussion. You can take a look at the [FormatCustomized](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformat.cs,434) (.Net Framework) method. Would that be less *naïve*? Or a standard Regex plus validation? I stated from the beginning that the example I posted was *just trivial string manipulation* and of course it's necessary to *generate a (much) more consistent procedure*. But that's what is done in the Framework, all the time. Can't you provide your own implementation? This also is done all the time.

Comment: @Jimi Let's just agree to disagree before we abuse the comment system any further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to go with a similar approach to what Jimi suggested. I only need the format string for this case, since the actual formatting is done by a shared class that takes in the format. I went with an approach to send a format that I want to base my manipulating on, in this case ShortDate. Then I send in the parts of that date that I want to use, in this case Day and Month. I then split the ShortDate and remove the parts that I don't want to resolve and concatenate it back into a string using the DateSeparator. It's not perfect, as it won't handle Time (or multiple different separators) in this current iteration but it does what it needs to at this point.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe there is a built-in way of formatting a date like this. As described in the [standard date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#MonthDay), the closest you can get is the "M" format specifier, which uses the `DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthDayPattern` property of the current culture. The output is not quite what you want in many cultures. E.g. in en-US, it is "April 17"